# Publish Windows form application - path too long

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish, pathtoolongexception

I'm trying to publish my application, but the bin\Debug\App.publish\ ect path is too long. I've found out that you can change this default path in web project by doint this c:\shortPath\ in the publish profile file, but i can't figure out how to do it for windows form application, i don't get any file i can edit.  I'm using VS 2012

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Output path in project properties-> build.